# insert code snippet with Grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, code-snippets

I need to insert a code snippet in my index.html page, only when Grunt livereload is running. The basic idea is to run a fake HTTP server (which is easy with a few lines of sinonjs), but only when I am in dev mode with Grunt.

I know it is feasible because Grunt livereload is himself inserting a snippet at the bottom of the HTML page, the question is how do I insert my own code snippet the same way the livereload task is doing ?

Many thanks,

David.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on where you want your injected HTML, you could do something like the following (completely untested):

```
var livereloadUtils = require('grunt-contrib-livereload/lib/utils');
var oldGetSnippet = livereloadUtils.getSnippet;
livereloadUtils.getSnippet = function() {
    var snippet = oldGetSnippet();
    // add your snippet stuff to snippet. So either:
    // snippet += '<p>your html</p>'; //or
    // snippet = '<p>your html</p>' + snippet;
    return snippet;
};
var lrSnippet = livereloadUtils.livereloadSnippet;
```

This will only inject after the `</body>`. Take a look through the [libs/utils.js](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-livereload/blob/master/lib/utils.js) to get a better idea of what is happening.